# Autodesk Forge Multiple Admins for an Application

Tags: autodesk-forge

Currently we have one user account that can access our registered applications. Is there any way to authorize more than one account to updated and change our applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time. But it is planned as a future enhancement. (Sorry - I don't have an ETA for you).

The best you can do right now is to create a single (shared) account for your entire team to use - which is better than relying on a single person who may leave.